# Kentico Form Aria-Label

Tags: forms, label, kentico

Is it possible to add aria labels to a Kentico form. I am adding the forms to my pages using the online form widget and I would like to add aria labels to each section to help make my site more ADA compliant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see the option by default in Kentico.  It's a good request though.  What you would need to do is to create your own form control that has the property.

https://docs.kentico.com/k10/custom-development/developing-form-controls

What you would look to do is clone the Textbox, add a property called "AriaLabel" to the form control's properties, then add this to the new code file for the textbox

In Properties region:

```
public string AriaLabel
{
    get
    {
        return ValidationHelper.GetString(GetValue("AriaLabel"), "");
    }
    set
    {
        if (txtValue.Attributes["AriaLabel"] != null)
        {
            txtValue.Attributes["AriaLabel"] = ValidationHelper.GetString(GetValue("AriaLabel"), "");
        }
        else
        {
            txtValue.Attributes.Add("AriaLabel", ValidationHelper.GetString(GetValue("AriaLabel"), ""));
        }
    }
}
```

In Page_Load at bottom:

```
if (txtValue.Attributes["AriaLabel"] != null)
            {
                txtValue.Attributes["AriaLabel"] = AriaLabel;
            }
            else
            {
                txtValue.Attributes.Add("AriaLabel", AriaLabel);
            }
```

Comment: This is a very viable solution @Jamn.  Also keep in mind Kentico is working on making controls more HTML5 compliant as you can see here.  http://ideas.kentico.com/forums/239189-kentico-product-ideas/suggestions/7161014-add-support-for-html5-input-types  I'd also make sure you comment about making the controls ADA compliant as well.  This could go hand in hand in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

If you will utilize label attribute for a field it will generate label tag for it in the HTML layout which will be accessibility compliant. Will that solve your purpose or are you looking specifically for aria-label tag only?

Comment: I do not want the label to be visible since I use the default text to show what the text box is for.